# MonoTouch - Location services in background

Tags: background, xamarin.ios, location

I have an app using MonoTouch which requires to capture GPS data every 2 mins in background. I found two ways to do it

1. using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges- works in background but not every 2 mins.
2. Using Timer and StartUpdatingLocation - Timer will be called every 2 mins and then update location.

The problem with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges is it doesn't get fired every 2 mins. So i cant use it. The other option of using Timer is better since it gives me a handle over time. But, will it run till my app is in the background for example one hour? Usually, ios apps gets 10 mins in background.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- You could set app's `UIBackgroundModes` to `location` and gets current location changes in background. Battery killer yet works.
- Other way is interpolate data from `Significant Location Changes` between `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` events.

Comment: Thats what i mentioned above. But my question is -   The problem with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges is it doesn't get fired every 2 mins. So i cant use it. The other option of using Timer is better since it gives me a handle over time. But, will it run till my app is in the background for example one hour? Usually, ios apps gets 10 mins in background.

Comment: According to Apple, `Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification`. So, either think that until next `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` event user didn't change phone's location, or eat phone's battery.

Btw, in theory, if user run on a road, you could receive events more often than once per 2 minutes  :)